# Как правильно: "паетки" или "пайетки"?

Tags: орфография

Пыталась прояснить этот вопрос, полезла в интернет. А там в одних случаях написано через Й — "пайетки" (пришиваемые на одежду блестки), а в других — без Й, "паетки". Так и не поняла, как правильно.
На слух просится Й.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В орфографическом словаре АН 2004 года зафиксировано "пайетки".